# Find the x that gives a specific value of a function

Tags: r, function, solver, uniroot

I have this function:

```
a <- 1
b <- 2 
get_y <- function (x,a,b) {
   a * b * x
}
```

And I want to create a function that takes in get_y and returns the x that makes y = 4 for example.
How would I do that?

Comment: So you want to solve this specific function or a more general form? If so, *how* general does it need to be? In particular, is `solve()` sufficient for your needs or do you have more complex functions?

Comment: for the simple case, you can use `get_x <- function(y, a, b) {y / (a * b)}; get_x(4, a, b) # 2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve

```
get_y(x,a,b) - 4 == 0
```

with [`uniroot`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/uniroot.html). You don't have to create a new function, an anonymous one will do it.

```r
a <- 1
b <- 2 
get_y <- function (x,a,b) {
  a * b * x
}

uniroot(\(x) get_y(x,a,b) - 4, c(0, 10))
#> $root
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> $f.root
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> $iter
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $init.it
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> $estim.prec
#> [1] 8
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

Following [ThomasIsCoding's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76905539/find-the-x-that-gives-a-specific-value-of-a-function/76905638?noredirect=1#comment135576599_76905638), here is a heuristic I many times use to find the search limits.

When the functions are (relatively) simple, use `curve` to plot the function. If I get it wrong at the first try, expand the limits until I no longer do. In this case, it was at the 2nd try.

```r
# doesn't display the horizontal line,
# the intersection between the function and the line y = 4
# must be outside the plot's y axis range
# curve(get_y(x, a = a, b = b), from = 0, to = 1)

# now yes, there's an intersection, the uniroot 
# search limits can be set to the interval [0, 10]
curve(get_y(x, a = a, b = b), from = 0, to = 10)
abline(h = 4)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: `uniroot` or `optimize` are powerful tools, +1! The only concern for those numeric methods is that we may have no idea about what is the feasible range for `x` to search the root. For example, here you assumed `c(-10, 10)` and the code works, but sometimes you may have no idea about what is the domain of `get_x` if there are some constraints.

Comment: I actually get an error:
Error: unexpected symbol in "uniroot((x) get_y"

Comment: @VictorNielsen What version of R are you using? That error many times comes from the new lambdas introduced in R 4.1 (2021-05-18). Try `function(x)` instead of ```\(x)```.

Comment: @VictorNielsen Time to update R?

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding You are right. I have edited the answer with a (very) crude way of finding the limits, which are different from the original answer's, btw.

Comment: Good reminder to do it. Thought my version was more recent, but you are right, it's from 2020.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `Ryacas` like below

```
library(Ryacas)
y <- 4
f <- sprintf("%s-%s", gsub("\\{|\\}", "", deparse1(body(get_y))), y)
x <- solve(ysym(f), "x")
```

and you will obtain

```
> x
{x==4/(a*b)}
```

---

If you want numeric solution of `x`, you can try the code below with a few more lines

```
get_x <- function(get_y, y, a, b) {
    f <- sprintf("%s-%s", gsub("\\{|\\}", "", deparse1(body(get_y))), y)
    s <- gsub("x==", "", solve(ysym(f), "x"))
    y_eval(yac_expr(s), a = a, b = b, as.r = TRUE)
}
```

such that

```
> get_x(get_y, 4, a, b)
[1] 2

> get_x(get_y, 4, a, 5)
[1] 0.8
```